# emberfire auth + cordova

Tags: cordova, authentication, emberfire, torii

As I understood, emberfire auth works via torii and includes the own torii-provider (`torii-providers/firebase.js`).

When I try to sign in, it runs `signInWithPopup` method from the firebase provider. It does not work when the application is running on a mobile device via cordova (`location.protocol` is equal to `"file:"`).

I've found a workaround:

1. I use the cordova plugin for authorization via google to get idToken.
2. I've overridden the provider to use `signInWithCredential`:

   ```
   export default ToriiFirebaseProvider.extend({
     open(idToken) {
       const firebaseApp = get(this, 'firebaseApp');
       const credentials = get(firebaseApp, 'firebase_.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential')(idToken);
       return firebaseApp.auth().signInWithCredential(credentials);
     }
   });
   ```

It works now, but I'm not sure that it's the right solution?

Answer (score 0):

So, you want a redirect instead of a pop-up?
If that's what you want, just set the redirect option:

```
this.get('session').open('firebase', { provider:'google', redirect: true })
```